# How to select the parent that contains a child has href tag with certain url

Tags: jquery

I need help to select this parent with the red rectangle that has the td child with the red marked certain URL

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42501580/45658520-a13ed600-baef-11e8-8f1a-fdac9fb8e67d.png

Comment: Hey Marwa. Please edit your question so that all necessary code to reproduce your issue is **in the question itself**. Additionally, make sure to include any attempts you've made to solve this problem on your own, rather than simply telling us what you "need". If you haven't made any attempts of your own, consider doing some more research, making an attempt, and returning when you've got some code for us to debug :)

Comment: To push you in the right direction, it sounds like you want a combination of an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) that looks for the specific `a[href=www.mysite.com]` and [`.closest("tr")`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know it's always going to be the grandparent of the link, you can use `parent()` twice.

```js
var link = $('a[href="http://example.com"]').parent().parent();

link.fadeOut();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="foo">foo1
  <td class="bar"> foo2
    <a href="http://example.com">foobar</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thank so much, actually now i want to select a class located inside the link variable, so i tied this code but didn't work: link.$(".num-hold").hide();
so what is the right code to select the "num-hold" class ??

Comment: `link.children(".num-hold").hide();`

Comment: thanks again :)
last query please, is there a function in query other than hide() to make the element like in-active and not clickable (removing the mouse events)

Answer (score 0):

You do it by jaunty attribute selector. Something like this may help

```
var linksToGoogle = $('a[href="http://google.com"]');
```

Invade you are interested in attributes starting with certain URL then use this 
var

```
allLinksToGoogle = $('a[href^="http://google.com"]');
```

And then you can use closest method to find parent for example

```
closest('.cart_item')
```